# $(document.body).css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to change the background image of my HTML body with a .js but nothing happens. Do I need to put the Javascript code inside my HTML?

```
function plano1() {
    alert('you');
    $(document.body).css('background-image', 'url(img/planoSelected.png)');
}
```

This is the complete function I have been trying to do. Google Chrome shows the alert, but doesn't do the `$(document.body)`. What am I supposed to do?

**Notes**: I use the function with a "onmouseover". I have already tried to use:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/planoSelected_2.png)');

$("body").css('background-image', 'url(img/planoSelected_2.png)');
```

Comment: You should go into the inspector and see if that image exists in that location.  Your code is fine.

Comment: And check if JQuery is loaded before you call this function, otherwise code looks good. Either image not available, or JQuery not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery code should be called at the bottom of the page, above the closing body tag.

Load jQuery first:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/planoSelected_2.png)');
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, but there are a few reasons why this *might* not work.

1. Make sure the image paths are correct, relative to the script's location
2. Is `plano1` called?
3. Make sure jQuery is actually loaded
4. Make sure the DOM is ready when calling the function (use `$(document).ready` if not sure)
5. Make sure there are no errors in the code before `plano1` is called

If these things are all right, and it still doesn't work, check if your `onmouseover` is working at all. Simply alert or log something in the console.